# Add Undo/Redo functionality in ArcMap to ArcPy script with manually started edit session

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase

I've written a set of simple ArcPy scripts for use with ArcMap 10.5.1 in versioned PostgreSQL Enterprise geodatabases. They're loaded into an add-in toolbar and intended to be used like a speed dial of shortcuts for updating specific attributes during a manually started edit session within ArcMap.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
SelectedLayer = [lyr.longName
    for lyr
    in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    if lyr.getSelectionSet()]
#Stops script unless there is a selection
if len(SelectedLayer) < 1:
    print "Selection required"
    exit()
#Iterates through selected layers and applies 1 to all selected features for Test attribute
for layer in SelectedLayer:
    ScaleLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer)
    ScaleSelection = ScaleLayer.getSelectionSet()
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ScaleLayer, 'Test') as ucursor:
        for row in ucursor:                              
            row[0] = 1
            ucursor.updateRow(row)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

The script works, but I've hit a roadblock for including Undo/Redo functionality, which is vital.

startOperation() and stopOperation() seem to be the way to do this, but the commands don't recognize that the user is already in an edit session. To use these commands, I have to also add startEditing, which breaks the Undo/Redo stack in place and can result in strange errors if Undo is used. Oddly, including stopEditing after stopOperation also does not recognize an edit session is in place. Here is a working version of the code that includes those elements:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
SelectedLayer = [lyr.longName
    for lyr
    in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    if lyr.getSelectionSet()]
#Stops script unless there is a selection
if len(SelectedLayer) < 1:
    print "Selection required"
    exit()
#Iterates through selected layers and applies 1 to all selected features for Test attribute
for layer in SelectedLayer:
    ScaleLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer)
    workspace = ScaleLayer.workspacePath
    edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
    ScaleSelection = ScaleLayer.getSelectionSet()
    edit.startEditing(True, True)
    edit.startOperation()
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ScaleLayer, 'Test') as ucursor:
        for row in ucursor:                              
            row[0] = 1
            ucursor.updateRow(row)
    edit.stopOperation()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: I think you need to review how editing in the UI operates, then try to recreate that with your script.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Is there a method for determining how the UI completes the same process?